# Where do I put - in which file, to persist routing rule (sudo ip r a IP via 192.168.1.1) on reboot,I just added?

Tags: networking

So where do I put this rule? Can I do it with Network manager GUI application? If so how do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Base on your question I have to assume you are using `juno`, and `juno` is based on Ubuntu 18.04

---

Haven't configure any route rule but I've read that Ubuntu 18.04 uses `netplan` https://netplan.io/ and no more `/etc/network/interface`

[image]

Maybe reading the following links could help you

- https://blog.ubuntu.com/2017/12/01/ubuntu-bionic-netplan
- https://netplan.io/examples#source-routing
- https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2378969